# Iterating over a 3D numpy array column and changing the value to the neighbor if is below to a number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, optimization

I have a 3D numpy array with floats where the values of each element need to be  replaced with the neighbor (i-1) if the value is less than value (vmin). The code implemented is quite inefficient:

```
def replace_values(B,vmin,nt,nx,ny):
    # B is a numpy array 
    # nt, nx ny the dimensions
    for z in xrange(0,nt):
        print i
        for y in xrange(0,ny):
            values=B[z,:,y]
            if numpy.amin(values)==0:
                for x in xrange(1,nx):
                    if B[z,x,y]<vmin:
                        B[z,x,y]=B[z,x-1,y]
    return B
```

Is there any way to implement iterators in order to improve the speed?

One limitiation that I have the size of the array, is almost the size of the RAM memory, a copy cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your inner loop is working on a 1d view, so can be coded as:

```
In [386]: values=np.random.randint(0,10,20)
In [387]: values
Out[387]: array([1, 5, 9, 4, 6, 7, 1, 5, 6, 4, 4, 3, 9, 5, 8, 5, 0, 3, 1, 2])
In [388]: np.amin?
In [389]: for x in range(1,len(values)):
     ...:     if values[x]<5:
     ...:         values[x]=values[x-1]
     ...:         
In [390]: values
Out[390]: array([1, 5, 9, 9, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 5, 8, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
```

If so, one goal is to speed this up, possibly with one of the ufunc `accumulate` functions (think of the action of `cumsum`).

The next question is, can we avoid the iteration on the other 2 dimensions.  With some transpose and reshape we could condense that into iteration on 1d, but that doesn't save time. And it is easier to test idea on a 2d array than a 3d.

I was going to suggest `apply_along_axis` to take care of the iteration details, but it doesn't work in-place or even take an `out` parameter).

=======================

Let's try applying this action to all the values of a 2d array.

```
In [398]: val2d=np.array((x1,x1+2, x1-2))
In [399]: val2d
Out[399]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  9,  4,  6,  7,  1,  5,  6,  4,  4,  3,  9,  5,  8,  5,  0,  3,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  7, 11,  6,  8,  9,  3,  7,  8,  6,  6,  5, 11,  7, 10,  7,  2,  5,  3,  4],
       [-1,  3,  7,  2,  4,  5, -1,  3,  4,  2,  2,  1,  7,  3,  6,  3, -2,  1, -1,  0]])
In [400]: for i in range(1,val2d.shape[1]):
     ...:     mask = val2d[:,i]<5
     ...:     val2d[mask,i]=val2d[mask,i-1]
     ...:     
In [401]: val2d
Out[401]: 
array([[ 1,  5,  9,  9,  6,  7,  7,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  9,  5,  8,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 3,  7, 11,  6,  8,  9,  9,  7,  8,  6,  6,  5, 11,  7, 10,  7,  7,  5,  5,  5],
       [-1, -1,  7,  7,  7,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  7,  7,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6]])
```

Then this 3d version should work (not tested):

```
for i in range(1, B.shape[1]):
    mask = B[:,i,:]<vmin
    I,J = np.where(mask)
    B[I,i,J] = B[I,i-1,J]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem : Forward-filling based on a mask**

Here's the problem described in a simplistic manner using a sample `1D` data.

Let's say the input data array is :

```
In [398]: a
Out[398]: array([4, 8, 2, 6, 3])
```

Let's say the mask based on which data is to be forward-filled is (filling is to be done on False positions) :

```
In [407]: mask
Out[407]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

First off, we create a masked based indices array

```
In [409]: mask*np.arange(mask.size)
Out[409]: array([0, 1, 0, 3, 0])
```

Next up, we do max accumulate, which forward fills the masked based indices array -

```
In [410]: np.maximum.accumulate( mask*np.arange(mask.size) )
Out[410]: array([0, 1, 1, 3, 3])
```

So, the final step is to simply index into the data array with these accumulate indices array -

```
In [411]: a[np.maximum.accumulate( mask*np.arange(mask.size) )]
Out[411]: array([4, 8, 8, 6, 6])
```

If you compare this with the original data array, we have forward filled it on the `False` positions from the mask.

**Final implementation**

Let's extend the `np.maximum.accumulate` based solution listed earlier to a `3D` case with few indexing methods and thus give ourselves a fully vectorized approach -

```
nt, nx, ny = B.shape
d0,d2 = np.where(B.min(1)==0)    
dim2_idx = np.maximum.accumulate( (B[d0,:,d2]>=vmin)*np.arange(nx), axis=1)
B[d0[:,None],np.arange(nx),d2[:,None]] = B[d0[:,None],dim2_idx,d2[:,None]]
```

Comment: Does ```mask``` consume as much memory as ```B```?

Comment: @wwii Nope `8` times less, same for `m1` being boolean arrays, but `m2` would probably be same as `B`. Let's hope it fits into asker's system memory :)

Comment: OP has a memory constraint.

Comment: @wwii Updated with an approach that uses masked elements and as such would be memory efficient.

Comment: It is wonking, many thanks. just a question how can I do in the other way around instead if assing i-1, assign i+1?

Comment: @gerocampo And `x` would be iterate how?

Comment: @gerocampo `for x in xrange(nx,0,-1)` or how?